# 3D vector angle calculation formula returns nan (acos argument bigger than 1 somehow... )

Tags: c++, vector, 3d, formula, angle

Because of *test1* and *test2* i know that the issue here is that the argument of acos is larger than 1 and thus i get nAn as result. But what exactly is wrong with my calculation?
Vectors are:
*v1*(3,4,0),
*v2*(0,1,0)
Expected result for the angle is 36.87°

```
double Vector::angle(const Vector& input) const
{
    double test1 = sqrt(this->length() * input.length()); //equals 2.23607
    double test2 = this->dotProd(input); //equals 4 

    double result = acos(this->dotProd(input) / sqrt(this->length() * input.length()));
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But what exactly is wrong with my calculation?

The `sqrt` at the denominator here:

```
double result = acos(this->dotProd(input) / sqrt(this->length() * input.length()));
```

It should be:

```
double result = std::acos(this->dotProd(input) / (this->length() * input.length()));
```

---

You could also infer that from dimentional analysis. If you assume the vector
represents, say, the displacement between two points in meters (m):

- The vector length has unit `[m]`;
- The dot product has unit `[m * m]`;

So you pass *acos* a parameter whose dimension is `[m]`, while it should be
dimensionless.